# multiple flutter emulator instances

Tags: flutter

On terminal instance 1 I navigate to /myprojects/my_app and execute `flutter run`

following is output :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           1.7s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                        15.1s
Xcode build done.                                           19.2s
This is taking longer than expected...
```

On a new terminal window I navigate to /myprojects/my_app and execute `flutter run`

following is output :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...

 ├─Assembling Flutter resources...                           1.7s
 └─Compiling, linking and signing...                         8.0s
Xcode build done.                                           12.4s
This is taking longer than expected...
```

But the existing emulator is overwritten with the existing emulator. How to run multiple flutter emulator instances ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type `flutter emulators` to get a list of all available emulators for you..

Then run `flutter emulators --launch <id>`

Start as many as you want with the above command

And finally, to run the app on all emulators you should do `flutter run -d all`